# How to Make HICON grayed?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an loaded standard windows icon (Destcop icon). And I need to make this Icon grayed. I didn't find how to load it grayed, so I tried to make it grayed. How to do this in simplest way?  I found how make gray(disabled) Icon from image:

```
HICON myIcon = (HICON)::LoadImage(
    AfxFindResourceHandle(MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_ID), RT_GROUP_ICON),
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_ID), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, 0);
```

But I don't now how to make gray Icon from color Icon....

Comment: This is similar but I trying to draw another one icon. And also  quality of DrawState is very poor.

Comment: Why don't you just use a decent icon editor and actually design the icon the way you want it??  Doing it programmatically, meh, pain in the rear to handle all possible icon formats and rarely very pretty.